# how to draw a LinearRing in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have written the below code to create a LinearRing.But nothing comes on the screen when I run this code

```
 var circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle(center, 250, 'XY');
 var circleFeature = new ol.Feature();
 var cordPoly = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);
 var coordinates = cordPoly.getCoordinates();
 var linearRing = new ol.geom.LinearRing(coordinates);
 circleFeature.setGeometry(linearRing);
 vectorlayer.getSource().addfeatures([circleFeature]);
```

Can anyone help me find the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 2,
      color: "red"
    })
  })
});

var circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle([0, 0], 100, 'XY');
vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature(ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom, 10)));

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [vectorLayer],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 16
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
```

According to the documentation, a LinearRing cannot be rendered on its own. Please try:

> circleFeature.setGeometry(cordPoly);

Comment: I tried that and I am getting a circle. But I need a linearRing on the screen.

Comment: If you zoom in you will notice that it is a LineString - a closed polygon. For your task you should create a polygon with ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(…): https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromCircle

Comment: There's also a syntax error in the question.  `ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle` is a method not a constructor, so it should be `var cordPoly = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);` without the `new`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I will try this and update

Comment: Again it is getting created as a circle and I could click all over the inner area of the circle.What I am trying to create is a  circular ring having hole at the center, so the polygon will look like a circular line string

Comment: @RalphL Could you please explain the meaning of "LinearRing cannot be rendered on its own"?

Comment: I have added a snippet. Is that the graphical result you want?

Comment: @RalphL That is really good one , But it is not circlular one.I am looking for a proper circular ring.

Comment: @RalphL I created the correct shape by adding more points in the fromCircle function.Thanks a lot :). And the required polygon was a LineString and I added that as per Mike's comment.

Comment: (0 , _polygonDefault.default).fromCircle is not a function

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to behave as a circular line you need to create a **linestring** from the corrdinates

```
 var circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle(center, 250, 'XY');
 var circleFeature = new ol.Feature();
 var cordPoly = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);
 var coordinates = cordPoly.getCoordinates();
 var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates[0]);
 circleFeature.setGeometry(lineString);
 vectorlayer.getSource().addfeatures([circleFeature]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have bounding box for a state and want to highlight that state drawing line around it. Can I do using your above code?